# Error during django template rendering

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates, django-views

One of the classes in my `models.py` file has this function

```
def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('index', kwargs={'slug': self.slug})
```

Here goes the `views.py` function:

```
def index(request):
    cardSets = CardSet.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'catalog/index.html', {'cardsets': cardSets})
```

And the piece of code from the `index.html`:

```
{% for cardset in cardsets %}
    <a href="{{ cardset.get_absolute_url }}">
     ...
```

My `urls.py` file looks like this:

```
urlpatterns = [url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
               url(r'^cardset/(?P<cardset_slug>[-\w]+)/$', views.show_cardset, name='show_cardset'),]
```

Now, when I'm trying to access the http://127.0.0.1:8000/ i receive the following error:

> In template
>   /home/dennis/PycharmProjects/eshop/templates/catalog/index.html, error
>   at line 7
>
> Reverse for 'index' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments
>   '{'slug': u'first-one'}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['$']

The line 7 is this bit:   `<a href="{{ cardset.get_absolute_url }}">`

Could you please advice me on what is going wrong and why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your get absolute url method;

```
def get_absolute_url(self):
    return reverse('show_cardset', kwargs={'cardset_slug': self.slug})
```

Comment: You have to call cardset detail view, not index view. show_cardset is the url name of cards detail view.

Comment: in `kwargs` rename `slug` to `cardset_slug`

Comment: @GeoJacob That works! Thanks! But could you please explain me why? So we go to the root page / -> the urtls.py redirect us to index view ( url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),) -> and this view renders the index.html page. Why does it care about the cardset_slug?  I might be unclear here :) Could you please explain what happens under the hood?

Comment: In your index page it is reffering the url to cards detail page, so it will check for the url which is mentioned for cards.